# How to execute a perl code in localhost?

Tags: apache, cgi

and I want to be able to view a sample web Perl code through localhost.

I have read in the internet that i should put those codes inside `cgi-bin` but I'm confused, I have a `cgi-bin` inside `/usr/lib/` and also inside `/var/www/`. So which one is it?

But whatever it is it's not working for both. when i put something inside it (a perl code) and execute in my browser: `localhost/perlcode.cgi` it says not found.

Although, if i enter this: `localhost/cgi-bin` it says forbidden. I tried `chmod` both `cgi-bin` still no luck.

So if anybody there knows the exact step how to make this work, feel free to answer me.

Im running apache server

Comment: Well, this depends on what server you are using. Apache? Have you set appropriate handlers for CGI execution? What paths are set in the configuration files?

Comment: **First** you need to write code against a standard that the server can communicate with (CGI is simple but inefficient, FastCGI is efficient but more complex, mod_perl is insanely powerful but even more complex, [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is excellent middleware adaptable to use any of the above. **Then** you need to configure your server to communicate with the program, how you do that depends on which server you are using and which means of communication you are using. Even if we assume CGI, we don't know if you are using Lighttpd, Nginx, Apache HTTPD or something else.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about @quentin

Comment: 1. You can't run any old Perl, it has to input and output data in one of several particular ways. 2. How you make your webserver talk to it depends on which webserver you use and which way you picked. We know neither of those so can't tell you what to do.

Comment: how do i know which webserver i am using, what command do i type in ubuntu? sorry im very new to linux and perl. this is very easy in windows and php.

Comment: What you need is a guide on how to set up Apache properly. Try [googling it](http://bit.ly/11Afx77). Basically you need to `chmod 775` the actual cgi file, and you need to tell your Apache that it should `execCGI` in the `cgi-bin` folder if that is not the case yet. It's easy on Windows with PHP because some guys at apachefriends.org have built xampp. That also supports Perl, btw, and there are howtos on how to set it up.